# Change opacity of certain color of Phaser.Sprite

Tags: javascript, colors, sprite, opacity, phaser-framework

I have a sprite sheet where black pixels stand for transperency. So, when I load a sprite from this sheet, I don't want those pixels to be shown.

Therefore my question is the following: Is there an easy way to tell Phaser that opacity of a certain color of a sprite should be turned transparent?

Comment: this might help: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/mask

Comment: You could use a mask as Elliot points out, or just convert your images to use actual transparency, since Phaser supports it out of the box.

Comment: If you still want to change the spritesheet on-the-go, you can try BitmapData.processPixelRGB() - http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.BitmapData.html#processPixelRGB . Just load the spritesheet into a BitmapData object, call this method and return (0, 0, 0, 0) (or really any colour with alpha 0) for each pixel that has (0, 0, 0) as its colour.

Comment: Nice find @KamenMinkov. I wonder how that would impact performance, but either way, put that into an answer with some code and I'd upvote that.

Comment: Why not just draw the transparent pixels instead of black pixels in your sprite .PNG file? You should use BitmapData only when you want to change the sprite in many different ways or combinations during the game.

Comment: @BdR Yes, after trying to solve it with Phaser without success, I decided to change the .PNG file. But I would have thought that a 2D engine like Phaser would have an easy way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to do this just one time, then you could do it with the help of online tools like [lunapic.com](http://lunapic.com).

Upload your sprite, select a color you want to make transparent and thats it.